# Jenkins android device not found/offline

Tags: android, jenkins

I'm using to make automatic build and releases of my android library.

One of the steps is, of course, automated testing. Since I can, I run the tests on a real device.

The issue is, I have to unplug then re-plug my device between every launch otherwise I get an error saying that my device is either not found or offline.

So the drivers are all fine since it's working the first time, but I can't figure out what's happening after that.

I'd love to be able to build and test release candidate everytime I push on develop but this is preventing me from doing it properly ;(

I tried re-installing everything with no changes. Has anyone else encountered the same issue or have a fix to this behaviour?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you can't use an emulator, you could try restarting the adb server at the start of each build.

Comment: Ended up with this solution : http://superuser.com/questions/699878/working-around-adb-waiting-for-device-issue
It's working at 99%.